# Batch: find a Task Name that starts with

Tags: batch-file

```
tasklist | find /I "ABC" 
if errorlevel 1 (
   REM Do Something
) ELSE (
   REM Do Nothing
)
```

I am trying to find a way to find a task that starts with "ABC" so if multiple tasks with a similar name are running it will trigger if there are 1 or more.

Comment: I'd suggest findstr.exe instead of find for regular expression searching. You can use `%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /i /r "\<ABC"` which will search for ABC at the start of the word. The /i makes it case insensitive. See [Findstr](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for 1 more tasks and execute as follows:

```
for /f "delims=" %%g in (' %__APPDIR__%tasklist.exe ^| %__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /i "\<ABC" ^| %__APPDIR__%find.exe /c /v ""') do set "_taskCount=%%g"
if "%_taskCount%" GEQ "1" (
REM Replace the echo line with whatever you wish to do.
echo 1 or more listed.
) else (
REM Replace the echo line with whatever you wish to do.
echo Zero are listed.
)
```

Edit: Some quick explanations:

`find.exe /c /v ""`
With this you are searching the count with /c and with /v "" you are searching for all lines which aren't blank. See [Find](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)

`GEQ` means Greater Than or Equal to. Since you want instances of one or more tasks. See the [If command](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html).

You can also type the following in the command prompt:

```
findstr /?
find /?
if /?
```

**Edit 2:** As per Compo's comments, this can be simplified if you do not need the count of the items found with the following:

```
%__APPDIR__%tasklist.exe | %__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /i "\<ABC" > nul
if not errorlevel 1 (
REM Do what you want if the item is found.
echo 1 or more found
) else (
REM Do what you want if no items are found.
echo No items found
)
```

This will check if any item matches the search. If the errorlevel is not 1, then an item matched. If it is 1, then no item matched.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd need to pipe through two separate `findstr.exe` processes. Regardless of that, the question does not require a count, it asks for "1 or more" which means it just needs to register a single match. For that reason, obviously a `for` loop is therefore unnecessary too.

Comment: Prefect and thank you!
I only needed it to do an update process if there were no open windows associated. 

The Edit 2 successfully bypasses the update process and then continues to check if instances are opened individually. Then opens any of the individual ones that are not currently open.